# How to recursively batch copy specific files in Windows based on number/qty given per file?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, recursion, copy

So basically, I want to try and copy a list of files and paste them within the same folder based on a given quantity.

For  example

```
C:\
    file 1 - 3(number of copies, which means a total of 4 instances of the file)
    file 2 - 4
    file 3 - 2
    file 4 - 10
```

It would become

```
C:\
    file 1
    file 1(2)(2 to N number enclosed in parenthesis meaning nth instance of a copy-pasted file in the same directory)  
    file 1(3)
    file 1(4)
    file 2
    file 2(2)
    file 2(3)
    file 2(4)
    file 2(5)
```

An [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/infTq.jpg)

Unfortunately couldn't come  up with the proper terms to search for batch scripts that could achieve what I want to achieve, so I hope I get an answer here.

Comment: There is no way to have more than one file with the same name _in the same folder_. You should show a _real example_ of input files (with proper names and locations) and the desired output with those files...

Comment: @Aacini  whenever you copy a file from windows and paste it in the same directory, a suffix like what you see in the example will happen.  See [here](https://imgur.com/a/h5d7)

Comment: In such a case, the files with the proper suffixes are _already_ in the folder as you show in your example, so I don't understand what is "what you want to achieve" with such files...

Comment: @Aacini as implied in the title, **"batch copy specific files in Windows based on number/qty given per file?"**  

imagine if i have 500 files in one folder and i need to copy at least 30 files with file 1 having 8 copies, file 2 having 10 copies, and so on and so forth up to file 30 with 20 copies...  I hope it's clear for you.

Comment: Where the file names and the number/qty come from? The Batch file should show each file in the folder and request the number from the user? Or is there a text file with a list of file names and the desired quantity? What is the format of such a file? In which path is such a file located? What to do if a file in the list does not exist in the folder? Please, do _NOT_ add a ton of additional details in comments! You should edit the question instead... **`:(`**

Comment: @Aacini i'll make it brief:   

multiple copies of 1 file times 30 files and each file has a specified quantity of my choosing of how many times it copies itself.  I need a batch script that could achieve this vs me manually copying a file n times and moving on to the next file and such.